# How to use Amazon s3 as a Codeigniter library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I created a file called `awslib.php` and put it in the `application/libraries` folder. These are the contents of awslib.php:

```
<?php

class Awslib {

    function Awslib()
    {
        require_once('sdk-1.5.6.2/sdk.class.php');
    }
}
```

Also in the libraries folder is the PHP sdk as a folder named `sdk-1.5.6.2`.

On my home controller I am loading the library and instantiating the s3 class:

```
$this->load->library('awslib');
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
```

When I load my homepage I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AmazonS3' not found in /var/www/application/controllers/home.php on line 23
```

Why isn't it working?

Note: the problem isn't with s3, I can get it to work fine when I store it outside codeigniter and load the demo files that come with the sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) directly. Most SDKs don't play nicely in CI unless wrapped up.

I highly recommend using the amazon-s3 [library](https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3) (or rather, the [spark](http://getsparks.org/packages/amazon-s3/versions/HEAD/show)).

Comment: yes I was using their SDK directly. Now here are my concerns about using one of the CI libraries. I was able to get the spark one you linked to working easily. But will these third party libraries be far worse performance wise than the native Amazon sdk? For one they aren't updated as much and while looking at the config for this particular library I didn't see any cache option whereas the Amazon sdk provides a cache option where you can enter a value like "apc". Anyway my only concern is, how performance friendly are these compared to the native sdk?

Comment: As far as I know, the libraries make use of the SDK. I would recommend the library (or spark) you want something functional out of the box, though yes, they're not 100% complete. If performance is a concern, you can always run some unit tests and measure and compare them?